# ActiveMQ JMS Connection Error with Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jms, activemq-classic, tomcat9

I have currently configured my Tomcat's `context.xml` like this:

```xml
<Resource name="jms/ConnectionFactory" auth="Container" type="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory" description="JMS Connection Factory" factory="org.apache.activemq.jndi.JNDIReferenceFactory" brokerURL="tcp://MY_LOCALHOST_URL:7270" brokerName="LocalActiveMQBroker" useEmbeddedBroker="false"/>
    
<Resource name="AppJms-HVDIVD17CA50359" auth="Container" type="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory" factory="org.apache.activemq.jndi.JNDIReferenceFactory" physicalName="APP.QUEUE" />
```

I have my `activemq.xml`:

```xml
<transportConnectors>
    <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
    <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    <transportConnector name="appjms" uri="tcp://MY_LOCALHOST_URL:7270?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
</transportConnectors>
```

And I am starting the JMS in Java Code like this:

```java
public void createMessageSubscriberJms(String host, int port, String jmsDestination) throws JMSException, UnknownHostException {
    
    String hostname = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName();
    String providerEndpoints = "tcp://" + hostname + ":" + port + "?wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=7200000";

    // Set the trusted packages/classes to move back and forth on the ActiveMQ JMS service.
    ArrayList<String> trustedClasses = new ArrayList<String>();

    trustedClasses.add("com.gtt.common.shared.GTCMessage");

    // Obtain the factory
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();

    activeMQConnectionFactory.setBrokerURL(providerEndpoints);

    // Add the trusted packages/classes to the ActiveMQ consumer.
    //activeMQConnectionFactory.setTrustedPackages(trustedClasses);
    activeMQConnectionFactory.setTrustAllPackages(true);

    //Create the connection
    setQueueConnection(activeMQConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection());
    getQueueConnection().setClientID(this.getName());

    // Make a session
    setSession(getQueueConnection().createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE));

    getSession().createQueue(jmsDestination);

    // Create the destination
    Destination destination = getSession().createQueue(jmsDestination);

    String selector = "JMSCorrelationID = '" + getActionRequest().getOriginId() + "_" + getActionRequest().getRequestId() + "'" ;

    setConsumer(getSession().createConsumer(destination, selector));
    getConsumer().setMessageListener(new DefaultMessageListener(this));

    // Start ...
    // We'll need a message store now
    gtcMessages = new GTCMessageQueue<GTCMessage>();

    getQueueConnection().start();
}
```

But when I start Tomcat and the method is invoked I get the following error:

```
Name [AppJms-HVDIVD17CA50359] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [AppJms-HVDIVD17CA50359].
```

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong? I am sure the same configuration worked when I was on an older version of Tomcat and ActiveMQ.

Currently I am using Tomcat 9.0.45 and ActiveMQ 5.16.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of `AppJms-HVDIVD17CA50359` looks a little strange to me:

```xml
<Resource name="AppJms-HVDIVD17CA50359" auth="Container" type="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory" factory="org.apache.activemq.jndi.JNDIReferenceFactory" physicalName="APP.QUEUE" />
```

It looks like you're defining a JMS queue since the `physicalName` attribute is `APP.QUEUE`. However, the `type` is `org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory` which is the proper `type` for a JMS connection factory, not a queue. Furthermore, the `org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory` class doesn't have a `physicalName` attribute. I think you should be using `org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue` here for the `type`, e.g.:

```xml
<Resource name="AppJms-HVDIVD17CA50359" auth="Container" type="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue" factory="org.apache.activemq.jndi.JNDIReferenceFactory" physicalName="APP.QUEUE" />
```

It's worth noting that you don't appear to be using `AppJms-HVDIVD17CA50359` or `jms/ConnectionFactory` in this code. I don't see any JNDI lookups using these names. Therefore, it's possible you could simply remove these resource definitions from your `context.xml` (assuming nothing else in your application uses them) and that would likely resolve the error as well.

That said, I would encourage you to use these resources as it will make it much easier to update your application in the future because if you need to change the connection factory or queue configuration then you'll only need to modify `context.xml` rather than your application's code. This is one of the major benefits of running your application in a server like Tomcat.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I used the context XML to implement the code. The problem was in the publisher code and not the consumer code. I used the `jms/ConnectionFactory` to get ActiveMQ connection factory and create a queue from that and ditched the Queue definition from the context.xml. Your inputs helped. The code is pretty lengthy so cant post in a reply to show you. But I got it to work! Thanks!